# calculating distance from google distance calculater then multiplying with number but The

Tags: javascript

how can i remove string when multipying the value with a number. with this code error comes up as NaN because of the alphabets from google distance calculater. how can i remove that "km" or "miles" in the end of result to multiple with a number and then display that result on a label

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="3">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        Source:
        <input type="text" id="txtSource" value="heathrow terminal 5" style="width: 300px" />
        &nbsp; Destination:
        <input type="text" id="txtDestination" value="bath road, tw6" style="width: 300px" />
        <br />
        



        <input type="button" id="calufare" runat="server"  value="Get Route" onclick="GetRoute()"/>
        <hr />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="2">
        <asp:Label ID="dvDistance" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label> 
        <asp:Label ID="dvDuration" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="rate" runat="server" Text="2.5"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="Fareid" runat="server" Text="Price£  "></asp:Label>

        <script>

            
        </script>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="dvMap" style="width: 1000px; height: 200px">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div id="dvPanel" style="width: 500px; height: 200px">
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var source, destination;
    var directionsDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
        new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': false });
    });

    function GetRoute() {
        var heathrow = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4711620, -0.4523710);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 7,
            center: heathrow
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
       
        //*               FOR PRICE CALCULATION                         * //
       
  




        //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
        source = document.getElementById("txtSource").value;
        destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

        var request = {
            origin: source,
            destination: destination,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        };
        directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }
        });

        //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
        var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [source],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
                var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
                var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
                dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
                dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
                dvDuration.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;
 var distanceMeters = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;

        rate=document.getElementById('Fareid').innerHTML = rate * distanceMeters;

            } else {
                alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
            }
        });
    }


</script>






























    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Losing the unit of measure is a bad idea.  You're going to get very different prices if the distance is in miles and you calculate as if it's in km and visa versa.  Also, why aren't you just using google maps to get the distance?  (Different algorithm?)

Comment: no its jsut the alphabets i want to take out wich doesnt let calculation to complete.

Comment: Show us the rendered code. Not the server-side version.

Comment: im gona post the whole page im working on to the snippet if u can have a look on that please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this
var rate = document.getElementById('rate').value;

```
            var distanceMeters = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.value;

            rate=document.getElementById('Fareid').innerHTML = rate * distanceMeters;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 dvDistance = parseInt(document.getElementById('dvDistance').innerHTML);
 var rate = document.getElementById('rate').value;
 document.getElementById('Fareid').innerHTML = rate * dvDistance;
```

Comment: It's quite different.  Obviously you didn't try it

Comment: it is in question you can have a look i changed on that as well